# Get unicode characters from a variable value Jupyter notebook (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, jupyter-notebook, emoji

I'm having a variable which is having a unicode of a character
ex:-

```
a = unicode_list[1]
print(a)
```

outputs

```
U0001F600
```

Now I need to get the character represent by this unicode
ex :- I need to get output as

following is not going to work,

```
a='\U0001F600'
print(a)
```

Because I'm getting unicodes from a list and I have to iterate through it using a variable.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
chr(int(a[1:], 16))
```

So, from inside: you get the string without the prefix '`U`', then you convert it to an integer, base 16.  Last step, you transform the integer into character (which is Unicode in python3).